# HTML5 - pattern attribute won't work properly

Tags: html, validation

Due to the fact that I have been making websites for 2 years now, I feel pretty embarrassed to ask this question, but for some reason, this code won't work:

```
<input type="number" name="ov_number" pattern="[0-9]{8}" required>
```

I am trying to make this `input` so that it only allows 8 numbers. No other characters, nothing less, nothing more. The problem I am having is, the webpage will tell me if the input is empty, I can't set any other character then numbers, but it allows for the `input` to have more or less then 8 characters.

I feel like I am missing something very stupid, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `pattern` attribute *only* works for inputs with their `type` attribute set to `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email`, or `password`. For other values of `type` `pattern` will be ignored. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)